# Vim. Restore an unlisted buffer

Tags: vim, buffer

Is there any way to restore an unlisted buffer in Vim and send it back to the list of buffers?

For example:

```
:ls!
  1# "one.txt"
  2% "two.txt"
  3u "three.txt"
```

Can I send the third buffer back to the list?

```
:ls
  1# "one.txt"
  2% "two.txt"
  3  "three.txt"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch to your unlisted buffer and reset the `'buflisted'` option:

```
:buf 3
:set buflisted
```

Comment: `:b3` alone was enough for me; that automatically brought that file back to the listed buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Or, another way:

```
:badd three.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Open unlisted buffer and edit it:

```
:b3
:e
```

Or in one line:

```
:b3|e
```